# Google Analytics for iOS - minimum deployment target?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods

I'm trying to install [Google Analytics for iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) using cocoapods, and see this error:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> 'Google/Analytics' required by 'Podfile'
>
> Specs satisfying the 'Google/Analytics' dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

So, how can I get minimum deployment target for analytics? [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) gives no clue. My app should support iOS 6.0, btw.

Comment: I also facing the same error, do you get any solution for this?

Comment: Nope. When I will find solution I will post an answer.

Comment: I've managed to bypass problem by downloading SDK directly, without cocoapods: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download#download_sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is described here: [cocoapods spec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/4/9/c/GoogleAnalytics/3.17.0/GoogleAnalytics.podspec.json)

```
"platforms": {
"ios": "5.0"
```

},

So right now the support is iOS 5 and up.